# MPEG-DASH m4s file format

Tags: mpeg-dash

I am trying to find info about MPEG-DASH segment m4s file.

Where can I fine documentation about MPEG-DASH m4s file format?

Comment: This might be a better question for https://superuser.com/

Comment: @sniperd though too broad for SU, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The m4s is a part of the ISO base media file format- you can find the spec here:

- https://www.iso.org/standard/68960.html